# Center Align Chapter Title in XeLatex

Tags: xetex

I am using the following packages to get times new roman font:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex} %compile with XeLatex
\ifluatex                    %or LuaLatex
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman} % text font
\setmathfont{XITS Math} % Times Roman math font
\else\ifxetex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
% possibly need to choose a suitable math font in my thesis:
\else
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\fi\fi
```

I am unable to center-align my chapter titles. I have used different packages, but no one is working. So far I have used

```
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter

\xpatchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{%
  \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak%
}{%
  \Huge \bfseries\centering #1\par\nobreak%
}{\typeout{Patched makeschapterhead}}{\typeout{patching of @makeschapterhead failed}}


\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{%
  \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
}{%
  \huge\bfseries\centering \@chapapp\space \thechapter
}{\typeout{Patched @makechapterhead}}{\typeout{Patching of @makechapterhead failed}}

\makeatother
```

also,

```
 \chapter{\centering Chapter Title}
```

and

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem was due to '`sectsty`' package, adding

```
\chapterfont{\fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont\centering}
```

after '`\include{chapter tilte}`' solved the issue.